# How to get the second value of a vector that is in a map?

Tags: c++

I have got this code in my c++

```
map<int,vector< pair <vector<int>,int> > > m;
```

And i want to get the `int` that is in the first vector hence i tried this code.

```
m[y].second;
```

But i got this error:

```
No member named 'second' in 'std::__1::vector<std::__1::pair<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, int>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, int> > >'
```

By `m[y]`,i expect to get the vector and by `.second` i expect to get the integer,so what is the problem?

Comment: `m[y]` is not a pair, so no `second` member. Look at the definition of `m`, what does it hold? How do you access *that*?

Comment: Shouldn't `m[y]` give me the value that is at index `y`?

Comment: `m` is a map. It gives you the value that the integer `y` is mapped to. That value is a vector...

Comment: @StoryTeller oh i see,thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By `m[y]`, I expect to get the `vector`

That's right, you get a reference to `vector<pair<vector<int>,int>>` from `m[y]` expression

> and by `.second` I expect to get the integer

No, `vector<pair<vector<int>,int>>` does not have `.second` member. You need one more dereference, either

```
m[y][0].second
```

or

```
m.at(y).front().second
```